# Awk if(cond1||cond2) filters nothing

Tags: bash, awk

Here's what I want to run in theory

```
    awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
               {if( $4 != "" || $4 != "Store Number")
               print $2}' $file >>out;
```

Instead I get all records from $file (i.e. no conditions applied)

However, I have checked that the following works:

```
    awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
               {if( $4 != "")
               print $2}' $file >>out;
```

Tried most combinations of phrasing including !(cond1 || cond2), !~, if((cond1) || (cond2)), but none work. I am running awk in Windows 10 bash.

Comment: `$4 != "" || $4 != "Store Number"` is always true. A string is always either not empty or not some specific string. Did you mean `&&`?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} $4 != "" && $4 != "Store Number"' "$file"` should work

Comment: I want a fruit where that fruit is not a banana OR not a strawberry. So... any fruit at all (a strawberry is not a banana, therefore it passes the filter, and a banana is not a strawberry so it too passes the filter). You want an AND `&&`instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$4 != "" || $4 != "Store Number"
```

The *only* string that can fail that condition is one that is both `""` and `"Store Number"` at *the same time!*

Since that is clearly not possible, it won't filter anything, as you have seen.

You probably meant to use `&&`.

---

As an aside, you can simplify your code a little if you use the condition part of `awk`:

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
$4 != "" && $4 != "Store Number" {print $2}
```

Answer (score 0):

not a or not b includes everything (unless a==b).

Answer: !=a && !=b

Thanks for the quick answers;; Time to brush up on my sets/logic.